# Finding estimates of a Linear Regression Equation - R

Tags: matrices, statistics, regression

I'm new to **Statistics** and **R**. I'm currently looking through a book called "Discovering Statistics using R". Although the book implies you don't need any statistical background, some of the content isn't covered/explained properly (in my opinion), despite being recommended for beginners... It's a great book though, apart from covering the following:

I'm trying to look at the relationship between x1, x2 and the response variable y using linear regression.

```
x1=c(  5,  6,  7, 12, 4,   9,  2, 4,   1,  8)
x2=c(  1,  6, 10, 11, 1,   2,  4, 6,   1,  3)
y =c(8.5, 11, 12, 20, 9, 5.5, 11, 5, 2.3, 12)
```

The linear regression model relating x1, x2 with y is: `y = β0 + β1x1 + β2x2`

The matrix form is `Y = Xβ` (where `Y` is the matrix form of `y`, `β′ = (β0, β1, β2)` and `X = (1, x1, x2)`.)

How do I go about finding the estimates of β using the following equation?

$$\widehat{β} = (X′X)^{−1} X′Y$$

If you could point me in the right direction or give another example/reference in **R** so I can figure this one out, that would be great.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but given that R is on its way out you might be better off looking into the likes of Stata, Matlab, Python, Julia, or C, depending on your computer skills and specific needs.

Comment: I already use Matlab for digital imagery and program in C++ but I'm trying to get my head around R as that's the statistical language/package that seems to come recommended around here. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: I've answered the question. FYI [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) is also good site for statistics-related questions, although anything related to use of R alone belongs on stackoverflow itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some R code that computes the coefficients using linear algebra $\widehat{β} = (X′X)^{−1} X′Y$, and then using R's built-in function `lm`. As you point out, the first column of $X$ in the model $y=X\beta$ is a column of 1s.

```
# Your data
x1=c(  5,  6,  7, 12, 4,   9,  2, 4,   1,  8)
x2=c(  1,  6, 10, 11, 1,   2,  4, 6,   1,  3)
y =c(8.5, 11, 12, 20, 9, 5.5, 11, 5, 2.3, 12)

# Build inverse. Needs column of 1s for intercept.
# (matrix form of linear regression equation is y = Xb)
x0=rep(1,10)
X=t(matrix(c(x0,x1,x2),nrow=3,byrow=T))

# MASS for ginv matrix inversion function
library(MASS)
# Calculate coefficients using linear algebra
ginv(t(X) %*% X) %*% t(X) %*% y

# Calculate coefficients using R's built-in linear model function
lm(y ~ x1 + x2)
```

Note

- You need to install the `MASS` package before using it.
- The R operator for matrix multiply is `%*%`.
- Transpose is accomplished using `t()`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment. Great Answer. :D

Answer (score 0):

Affine regression: $y_i = w^T x_i +b + e_i$. Average over $i$ to obtain $\frac{1}{m} \sum_i y_i = w^T\frac{1}{m}\sum_i x_i +b +\frac{1}{m}\sum_i e_i$. This gives $\bar y = w^T\bar x +b \bar e$. Subtract this from the first equation to get $y_i -\bar y = w^T(x_i-\bar x) + e_i-\bar e$. Assume $\bar e=0$. Then what remains is centered linear regression. So under these assumptions, you can use affine, or center then linear regression